# Compromising Mongoose with REST API

Tags: java, node.js, rest, mongoose

I need to ask - I've got a `/users` endpoint and I want to add tasks to user, just like that: `/users/:username/tasks`. Should I create another model and route? I don't know how to add an ID to an array in Mongoose model and add a slug with `mongoose-url-slugs`.

I want it to be RESTful as much as I can. So this: `/users/:username/tasks` or `/tasks/:username`? If first, I need to know how to add ID to `tasks` in that model:

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const User = mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    tasks: Array
}, {
    timestamps: true
})

export default mongoose.model('User', User)
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, I believe you should create a new model **tasks**.

You can use a reference to **tasks** model like that:

```
tasks: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'tasks' }]
```

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

This route's better because you're adding a task to the user and not a user to the task
`/users/:username/tasks`

And to link then you can use mongoose's virtual: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/virtuals.html

Ex: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6608

```
UserSchema.virtual('tasks', {
  lookup: (doc) => {
    return {
      from: 'tasks',
      let: { userId: '$_id' },
      pipeline: [{
        $match: {
          $expr: {
            $and: [{
              $eq: ['$refId', '$$userId']
            }]
          }
        }
      }, {
        $project: { name: 1, createdAt: 1 }
      }
      ],
      as: 'tasks',
    }
  }
});
```

```
userModel.find().populate('tasks').lean(true);
```